# Calculate total checkboxes ticked and perform calculation (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, mobile, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have checkboxes created dynamically using shared preferences. The label for each checkbox is stored in  array.xml. How can I calculate the total number of checkboxes that are ticked and store the total in a variable and further use it for another calculation -- (total/totalCheckboxes)*100?

Here's a snippet of the Java class:-

```
    public class CheckBoxSharedPreferences extends Activity {
    ListView myList;
    Button getChoice, clearAll, button1;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyUserChoice";
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        getChoice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getchoice);
        clearAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearall);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                // code snippet to retrieve array values in ArrayAdapter
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Questionnaire));
        myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES)) {
            LoadSelections();
        }

        getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String selected = "";
                int cntChoice = myList.getCount();

                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList
                        .getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {
                    if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                        selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()
                                + "\n";
                        System.out.println("Checking list while adding:"
                                + myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        SaveSelections();
                    }

                }

                Toast.makeText(CheckBoxSharedPreferences.this, selected,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        //listener for clear all button
        clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ClearSelections();
            }
        });

        //listener for button1 (that transfers the activity to another intent
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(CheckBoxSharedPreferences.this,
                        result.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void SaveSelections() {
        // save the selections in the shared preference in private mode for the
        // user

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String savedItems = getSavedItems();
        prefEditor.putString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), savedItems);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }

    private String getSavedItems() {
        String savedItems = "";
        int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (this.myList.isItemChecked(i)) {
                if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                    savedItems += "," + this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                } else {
                    savedItems += this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return savedItems;
    }

    private void LoadSelections() {
        // if the selections were previously saved load them

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES.toString())) {

            String savedItems = sharedpreferences.getString(
                    MyPREFERENCES.toString(), "");
            selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));

            int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String currentItem = (String) myList.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                if (selectedItems.contains(currentItem)) {
                    myList.setItemChecked(i, true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Current Item: " + currentItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    myList.setItemChecked(i, false);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

and the array.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="Questionnaire">

        <item>abc</item>
        <item>jkm</item>
        <item>xyz</item>
        <item>abc2</item>
        <item>jkm2</item>
        <item>xyz2</item>
        <item>abc3</item>
        <item>jkm3</item>
        <item>xyz3</item>

</resources>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This snippet is useless, please add code where you are creating check boxes.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 added the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code where you want to get the total number of checked items and perform the calculation

```
int checkedCount = myList.getCheckedItemCount();
int totalCount = myList.getAdapter().getCount();
int calculatedValue = (totalCount/checkedCount) * 100;
```

Comment: thanks @Rohit5k2. I've edited the codes a bit, calculation seems to work fine but it doesn't give me the output that I need. I'll open up another question for it.

Comment: sure. that would be nice.